# Python bokeh legend color for inactive legends

Tags: python, bokeh

Want to change the background for inactive legend, then you click on it.

Couldn't find in in docs. Which is very strange.

[image]
In this case 'UK' is inactive. Now it has grey background. Is it possible to change it?

Thanks.

Comment: beside the docs, you can inspect any bokeh model using the method properties_with_values() (e.g. legend.properties_with_values() )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Couldn't find in in docs.

It's in the reference guide:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.Legend.inactive_fill_color

e.g. `plot.legend.inactive_fill_color = "blue"`

Comment: Really couldn't find it. Sometimes happens. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yup, no worries, just noting for general and future reference for anyone viewing this, glad it's working